# Google Compute Engine VM instance auto turned off

Tags: google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have a Bitnami Wordpress Multisite installed on Google Compute Engine. Recently, it was turned off repeatedly with no reason. I have rebooted it via the Bitnami control panel on Jul 2nd and it seemed to work, but now it does not. Here is my compute engine [7-day-report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePmMP.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check in this case is the [Google Compute Engine VM instance availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options) setting: it can be either **live migrate** or **terminate**, which tells Google Compute Engine what to do with your VM when the underlying host needs to undergo maintenance. Note that there's an `automaticRestart` setting as well, if you choose the **terminate** option.

This is a per-VM setting.

If it were set to "terminate", that may explain the issue you saw. Setting it to "live migrate" would mitigate the issue.

Comment: I've check that setting again and all these things are the same as you said but problem still happened

Answer (score 0):

You should check your quotas page, you may be running out of something !
Quotas can be found under compute engine menu on the left.

Comment: I'm firmly believe that's not the problem here as the largest of my quotas is just 20%. You can see it [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Eksi7.jpg)